# Undefined column error when using the output of a function as the table name

Tags: postgresql

I have a multi-tenant database where each tenant gets their own schema. Each schema has a set of materialized views used in full-text searches.

The following function takes a schema name and a table name and concatenates them into schema.table_name format:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_table_name(_schema text, _tbl text, OUT result text)
        AS 'select $1 || ''.'' || $2'
        LANGUAGE SQL
```

It works as expected in PGAdmin:

[image]

I'm trying to use this function in a prepared statement, like this:

```
SELECT p.id AS id,
        ts_rank(
          p.document, plainto_tsquery(unaccent(?))
        ) AS rank
        FROM create_table_name(?, 'project_search') AS p
        WHERE p.document @@ plainto_tsquery(unaccent(?))
        OR p.name ILIKE ?
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 42703 (undefined_column) column p.id does not exist
```

If I "hard-code" the schema and table name though, it works.

Why am I getting this error?

P.S. I should note that I am aware of the dangers of this approach, but the schema name always comes from inside my application so I'm not worried about SQL injection.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use a string as a piece of code.

Comment: Yeah, I should note that I'm very much NOT good at SQL. I was looking at the problem as a simple string interpolation problem... At the end of the day, all I need is take a variable and plug it into the 'FROM' portion of the SQL statement as a prefix to the table. The approach I'm using is because T-SQL doesn't allow for dynamic table names, based on what I've read.

Comment: @EgeErsoz: T-SQL is used by Microsoft SQL Server, not by Postgres. But yes, you can't mix dynamic SQL and static SQL in that way. You need use dynamic SQL for the complete final statement that you are using. As you mention a "prepared statement" you will need to concatenate the table name into the SQL string before you prepare the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the function result as table name in a query, but what you are actually doing is using the function as a table function. This “table” has only one row and one column called `result`, which explains the error message.

You need dynamic SQL for that, for example by using PL/pgSQL code in a `DO` statement:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   ...
BEGIN
   EXECUTE
      format(
         E'SELECT p.id AS id,\n'
         '       ts_rank(\n'
         '          p.document,\n'
         '          plainto_tsquery(unaccent(?))\n'
         '       ) AS rank\n'
         'FROM %I.project_search AS p\n'
         'WHERE p.document @@ plainto_tsquery(unaccent($1))\n'
         'OR p.name ILIKE $2',
         schema_name
      )
   USING fts_query, like_pattern
   INTO var1, ...;
   ...
$$;
```

To handle more than one result row, you'd use a `FOR` loop — this is just a simple example to show the principle.

Note how I use `format` with the `%I` pattern to avoid SQL injection. Your function is vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you, I will play with this. It seems like overkill though. Is there really no way to "interpolate" the value of the single column returned from the function directly into the FROM statement?

Comment: No, there is no way to execute dynamic queries in SQL.